# Printing SSRS graph report on multiple pages

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, rdl

I have graph report that is printing a lot of data on X axis. The output from the report is not adequate, there is not enough space between two points. For example if there 20 points to be displayed on one page, user can not see complete caption, they are overlapping. I want to set min space between points and print this report on more pages. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do to help solve this issue.

1) In the chart axis properties you can set the label rotation so the labels appear vertically.

2) The other thing you can do is set an expression for the DynamicWidth property in the chart properties, based on the number of points on the x - axis

3) Make sure the interactive report size is wide enough to accommodate the maximum width of the chart.

The images below show dynamic width working

[image: Example A]
[image: Example B]